# How can I remove all words from a string beginning with minus?

Tags: php

I tried this, but it seems to work only with alphanumeric characters?

```
\ba\w*\b  <- works
\b-\w*\b  <- doesn't work
```

How can I remove all the words from a string that starts with a hyphen?

Comment: What is your definition of a word?

Comment: it shouldn't change much, but have you tried escaping the - like this \- so like use \b\-\w*\b

Comment: `-` has no special meaning, has it?

Comment: @clentfort Only inside of a [character class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php).

Comment: The first word boundary `\b` doesn't match. It doesn't work between two non-word characters. You ought to use `(?<=\W|^)` there in place of `\b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_replace("/-\w+/", "", "-000 aaa -bbb ccc -ddd -eee")

gives: 
aaa  ccc

---

**EDITED 3 times:** As noticed in the comments - be it a stretch of the original question or not - all the suggested variants didn't work with -xx-yy-zz or qq-ww-ee, or -äüö. This one :

```
preg_replace("/(\s?)(?<=\s|^)(-)\S*\s*/", "$1", "-000 aaa -bbb ccc -ddd -eee-eee-eee -äüö fff-qqq-rrr äüö2 äüö-äüö-3 -ggg");
```

... produced the following:

```
 aaa ccc fff-qqq-rrr äüö2 äüö-äüö-3
```

Limitations apply: accented characters are acceptable; multibyte ones would certainly be a stretch.

Comment: This will also match `string-in-string` for `-in` and `-string` which might be undesired. (Therefore the the `\b` in the question)

Comment: Right. mario's comment addresses that.

Comment: But this example is not matching -äüö How can I achieve that?

Comment: See the edits above. You can also tweak it further to eliminate extra spaces.

Comment: ... the last version removes extra spaces.